# Animate open/close of top nav bar with vanilla JS/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to work myself off from using Bootstrap, but I've encountered something I've been unable to figure out.

For a responsive top nav bar, when I click on the hamburger menu, I'd like it to animate open and closed (depending on whether it was open or closed to begin with).

The issue I'm running into is the use of `display: none` on the nav killing any/all animations. The `.nav-top__nav-list` is what the animation needs to occur on, which has the display toggled from "none" to "block". I'm doing this for accessibility (meaning a screen reader won't hit this area unless the navigation is expanded). Is there another way I should be doing it to preserve the accessibility nature of being hidden, while still being able to animate the opening/closing of the nav menu?

```js
function topNavToggle() {
    var topNavList = document.getElementById("topNavList");
    var topNavToggle = document.getElementById("topNavToggle");
    if (topNavList.className === "nav-top__nav-list") {
        topNavList.className += " responsive";
        topNavToggle.className += " toggled";
    } else {
        topNavList.className = "nav-top__nav-list";
        topNavToggle.className = "nav-top__toggle-button";
    }
}
```

```css
.nav-top,
.navbar-nav {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 13;
}

.wrapper__1170-max-width {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

.display-desktop {
  display: block;
}
.display-mobile {
  display: none;
}

.nav-top {
  background: #466a62;
  min-height: 40px;
}
.nav-top__header {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 13;
}
.nav-top__header button {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  grid-column-start: 12;
  grid-column-end: 13;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  justify-self: right;
}
.nav-top__header button .bar-1,
.nav-top__header button .bar-2,
.nav-top__header button .bar-3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
.nav-top__header button.change {
  background: red;
}
.nav-top__header .toggled .bar-1 {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}
.nav-top__header .toggled .bar-2 {
  opacity: 0;
}
.nav-top__header .toggled .bar-3 {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}
.nav-top__header .nav-brand {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 12;
  grid-row-start: 1;
}
.nav-top__nav-list {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 13;
}
.nav-top__nav-list ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.nav-top__nav-list ul li {
  float: left;
}
.nav-top__nav-list ul li a {
  color: #FFF;
  display: block;
  padding: 11px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-top__nav-list ul li a:hover {
  background: #FFF;
  color: #18453b;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .display-desktop {
    display: none;
  }
  .display-mobile {
    display: block;
  }
  .nav-top__header {
    display: grid;
  }
  .nav-top__nav-list {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav-top__nav-list.responsive {
    display: block;
  }
  .nav-top__nav-list.responsive ul li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav-top" aria-label="primary">
    <div class="wrapper__1170-max-width">
        <div class="nav-top__header display-mobile">
            <span class="nav-top__brand">Menu</span>
            <button type="button" id="topNavToggle" class="nav-top__toggle-button" aria-label="Expand and collapse primary site navigation" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#topNavList" onclick="topNavToggle()">
                 <div class="bar-1"></div>
                 <div class="bar-2"></div>
                 <div class="bar-3"></div> 
             </button>
         </div>
         <div class="nav-top__nav-list" id="topNavList">
             <ul>
                 <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
             </ul>
         </div>
     </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: maybe you can try on click toggled display: block/none first and then with delay toggle class with animation styles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CSS, `display` property cannot be animated. You can use `height` or `max-height`. The advantage in using `max-height` will be that, the container will take optimal height even if you change font-size at different screen sizes with media query. So, I have used `max-height` with CSS transition. I have updated your code to get desired effect.

```js
function topNavToggle() {
    var topNavList = document.getElementById("topNavList");
    var topNavToggle = document.getElementById("topNavToggle");
    var topNavListLi = document.querySelectorAll("#topNavList li");
    
    if (topNavList.className === "nav-top__nav-list") {
        topNavList.className += " responsive";
        topNavToggle.className += " toggled";
        for (let i = 0; i < topNavListLi.length; i++) {
          var hiddenAttribute = document.createAttribute("hidden");
          //topNavListLi[i].setAttribute('hidden',false);
          topNavListLi[i].setAttributeNode(hiddenAttribute);
        }
    } else {
        topNavList.className = "nav-top__nav-list";
        topNavToggle.className = "nav-top__toggle-button";
        setTimeout(function(){
          for (let i = 0; i < topNavListLi.length; i++) {
            //topNavListLi[i].setAttribute('hidden',true);
            topNavListLi[i].removeAttribute('hidden');
          }
        },300);
    }
}
```

```css
.nav-top,
.navbar-nav {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 13;
}

.wrapper__1170-max-width {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

.display-desktop {
  display: block;
}
.display-mobile {
  display: none;
}

.nav-top {
  background: #466a62;
  min-height: 40px;
}
.nav-top__header {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 13;
}
.nav-top__header button {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  grid-column-start: 12;
  grid-column-end: 13;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  justify-self: right;
}
.nav-top__header button .bar-1,
.nav-top__header button .bar-2,
.nav-top__header button .bar-3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
.nav-top__header button.change {
  background: red;
}
.nav-top__header .toggled .bar-1 {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}
.nav-top__header .toggled .bar-2 {
  opacity: 0;
}
.nav-top__header .toggled .bar-3 {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}
.nav-top__header .nav-brand {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 12;
  grid-row-start: 1;
}
.nav-top__nav-list {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 13;
}
.nav-top__nav-list ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.nav-top__nav-list ul li {
  float: left;
}
.nav-top__nav-list ul li a {
  color: #FFF;
  display: block;
  padding: 11px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-top__nav-list ul li a:hover {
  background: #FFF;
  color: #18453b;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .display-desktop {
    display: none;
  }
  .display-mobile {
    display: block;
  }
  .nav-top__header {
    display: grid;
  }
  .nav-top__nav-list {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height .3s ease;
  }
  .nav-top__nav-list ul li {
    float: none;
  }
  .nav-top__nav-list.responsive {
    max-height: 170px;
    transition: max-height .3s ease;
  }
  .nav-top__nav-list.responsive ul li {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav-top" aria-label="primary">
    <div class="wrapper__1170-max-width">
        <div class="nav-top__header display-mobile">
            <span class="nav-top__brand">Menu</span>
            <button type="button" id="topNavToggle" class="nav-top__toggle-button" aria-label="Expand and collapse primary site navigation" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#topNavList" onclick="topNavToggle()">
                 <div class="bar-1"></div>
                 <div class="bar-2"></div>
                 <div class="bar-3"></div> 
             </button>
         </div>
         <div class="nav-top__nav-list" id="topNavList">
             <ul>
                 <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
             </ul>
         </div>
     </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: This is almost perfect, except that the hidden links can still be tabbed to with keyboard navigation or with screen reader use.Is there a solution here to make them hidden AFTER the nav has closed?

Comment: @JesseEarley I have updated the code by adding HTML5 `hidden` attribute when menu collapses. So, it will not be focusable by tabs and readable by screen readers. Hope it works for you now!

Comment: Thanks! One other question...
With the hidden attribute, if you stretch the browser window back out beyond the media query (when the nav is closed), the links are now hidden. I added a 'matchMedia' query in the JS, which does set the hidden attribute back to true when the browser window stretches with the nav closed...but the nav items remain hidden. Any ideas on that one?

Comment: EDIT: NM, I want to REMOVE the attribute, NOT set it to false. Even 'hidden=false' keeps the element(s) hidden from view.

Comment: @JesseEarley I have updated the code to add/remove `hidden` attribute instead of setting it `true` or `false`. Please check it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't animate between two values of display, so you're intuition was correct to use another way of hiding/showing the expanded menu. Here's an example using height, another example would be opacity.

```
  .nav-top__nav-list {
    height: 0;
    transition: height 0.15s ease-in;
  }
  .nav-top__nav-list.responsive {
    display: block;
    height: 180px;
  }
```

Comment: The effect works here, but I still have the issue of the links themselves being able to be tabbed to, either with keyboard navigation or with a screen reader. Using this method, how can I hide them after the animation concludes?

Answer (score 1):

`display: none` can not be animated. Instead you can use `visibility: hidden` and `visibility: visible`.

Comment: Using your method to hide, along with the solution above (except swapping height with max-height), this works...sort of. There's still a "hiccup" at the end of the animation before the menu bar closes entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Since display can't be animated, I normally do a 2-step approach using setTimeout or requestAnimationFrame. This is also the way some frameworks like ng-animate work internally. Something like:

```
var state = Enums.NavState.Closed;

function openNav() {
    state = Enums.NavState.Opening;
    var nav = $('.topNavList')
    nav.addClass('navVisible');

    requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        // This is async, so make sure we're still opening;
        if (state === Enums.NavState.Opening) {
            state = Enums.NavState.Open;
            nav.addClass('in');
        }
    })
}
```

And some sample css:

```
.navVisible {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 300ms;
}

.navVisible.in {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Can provide a bit more detail on this solution, or alter the code I provided to incorporate your solution? I've attempted to use what you've provided, but I'm not seeing anything working on my end.

Comment: The key bit is just to set your element to `display: block` before you activate your css transition. My code is a simplified example showing the principle, your actual code would probably be much longer.